# Strange behaviour of getch()

Tags: c++, io, getch

I have a program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << int (_getch ()) << endl;
    }
    _getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

If I press keys like digits, alphabets and Enter, a single integer is displayed (per iteration of the loop). However, if I press keys like Insert, Delete, or the arrows, two integers are displayed at once.

Why does this behaviour occur?

Comment: Because some keys send two key-codes.

Comment: `conio.h` isn't necessary at all.

Comment: Are they displayed on the same line? Or is the loop just doing two iterations?
If it's the latter (and the first int is 0) that's perfectly normal for special keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [_getch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

When reading a function key or an arrow key, each function must be called twice;

The first call returns 0 (for F1-F10) or 0xE0 (224) (for others) , and the second call returns the actual key code.